# Pass value to partial view

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-mvc-5

I have the following on an ASP.NET MVC 5.0 master view:

```
@Html.Partial(MVC.Shared.Views._Base, new { MasterViewName = "core" });
```

Then on the master view I tried to get the value:

```
@model dynamic
@Model.MasterViewName;
```

But I get the error:

```
'object' does not contain a definition for 'MasterViewName'
```

What am I missing?

Thank you,
Miguel

Answer (score 4):

You can pass in additional information to the partial by adding data into the `ViewDataDictionary`.

In your example, it would look something like:

```
@Html.Partial(MVC.Shared.Views._Base, new ViewDataDictionary(ViewData) {{"MasterViewName", "core"}});
```

You could then access the `MasterViewName` data from the page using:

```
ViewData["MasterViewName"]
```